# Can I include the alertId in an Azure Alert custom payload

Tags: azure, alert, azure-application-insights

I am sending a custom payload from Azure alerts into a Logic App for generating customised emails. I wish to include a link to the alert that fired inside the email. The URL for this includes the value for alertId, which is available with the standard payload but isn't mentioned in the fields available for custom payloads [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log-webhook). Is there a way of including alertId in the custom payload?

A less desirable but acceptable alternative is to include a link to the Alerts list in Azure. This URL includes the value of the tenant id. Is there a way to obtain the tenant id either for inclusion in the alert payload or directly within the Logic App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like the alertId property is currently available under the custom JSON properties. Not an ideal solution, but there is some useful info if you parse the search results link including the tenant ID, Sub ID, Resource Group (for the workspace) and the workspace/application ID. I know this may not be perfect because alerts don't have to be in the same subscription or resource group, but at least it gets you the tenant ID:

portal.azure.com#@**{tenantId}**/blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/LogsBlade/source/Alerts.EmailLinks/scope/{"resources":[{"resourceId":"/subscriptions/**{subsriptionId}**/resourceGroups/**{resourceGroup}**/providers/microsoft.insights/components/**{workspaceId/applicationId}**"}]}/q/**{query}**